# Matlab mex options?

Tags: c++, matlab, gcc, mex

there is a mex compile command as follows:
`mex mexScale2seg.cpp -DUSEOMP CXXFLAGS="\$CXXFLAGS -fopenmp" LDFLAGS="\$LDFLAGS -fopenmp" -outdir "./private/" -I"./include/"`

in which `-DUSEOMP` used to transfer a macro definition to .cpp source file,
`-outdir` specify the dir to save output object file.

while   `-I"./include/"` tell the compiler another include directories.
there is no space between `-I` and `./include/`, but space exists between `-outdir` and  `./private/`.

in addition, `-` before command line options are also not unified.

So, my question is, when should I add `-` before command and when a (space) exists between commands and options?

Comment: The answer is of course to follow [the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html). As to why it's this way, well... I'm guessing that MathWorks would do it differently given a do-over. :) But I think it got this way because `mex` had to be a shell script and a perl script with familiar gcc-like syntax. Consistency be damned.